# Devise invitable: invite existing user

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise-invitable

I am using devise invitable in my application for inviting the users. If the user exists in the database I have to redirect him to signin screen otherwise to the signup screen if he is a new user. Even if I invite the user like: 
`User.invite!(:email => "jonny@email.com", :name => "Jonny")`, the data is getting entered in the database, then the user is always getting redirected to sign in screen. I had written the following for checking the email in invitations controller:

```
  def edit
    if User.exists?(:email => params[:email])
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    else
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    end
  end
```

Can some help me how I can handle this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For edit it should find a user by id rather than going on to the new_user_session_path. The edit method should contain the following piece of code.

```
def edit
if User.exists?
@user = User.find(params[:id])
else
  redirect_to new_user_registration_path
end
end
```